# Debian 6 NDISwrapper doesn't install correctly

Tags: linux, debian, wifi, kernel-modules, ndiswrappers

I'm using Debian 6. I've been trying to set up the Netgear N300 WiFi (model number WNA3100) adapter but haven't been successful. The Ndiswrapper was installed from .deb packages which I downloaded on one computer and transfered to the computer I'm haveing issues with. I have added it to /etc/modules

```
USERNAME@COMPUTERNAME:~$ sudo ndiswrapper
install/manage Windows drivers for ndiswrapper

usage: ndiswrapper OPTION
-i inffile       install driver described by 'inffile'
-a devid driver  use installed 'driver' for 'devid' (dangerous)
-r driver        remove 'driver'
-l               list installed drivers
-m               write configuration for modprobe
-ma              write module alias configuration for all devices
-mi              write module install configuration for all devices
-v               report version information

where 'devid' is either PCIID or USBID of the form XXXX:XXXX,
as reported by 'lspci -n' or 'lsusb' for the card


# /etc/modules: kernel modules to load at boot time.
#
# This file contains the names of kernel modules that should be loaded
# at boot time, one per line. Lines beginning with "#" are ignored.
# Parameters can be specified after the module name.

loop

ndiswrapper
```

But modprobe doesn't recognize it as present and I can't get online.

```
USERNAME@COMPUTERNAME:~$ sudo modprobe ndiswrapper
FATAL: Module ndiswrapper not found.
```

Answer (score 0):

I built and installed ndiswrappers on Debian wheezy just now. How do you know ndiswrapper is installed correctly on your system? Please give details of how you installed it. A standard way of installing it is via `module-assistant`. It will perform the necessary steps for you, including fetching the ndiswrapper-source source, building it, and installing it for you. Just type `m-a` on the command line and follow the menu options.

You write:

> I've been trying to set up the Netgear N300 WiFi (model number
>   WNA3100) adapter but haven't been succesful.

If you want help, you need to provide details of you did and what errors you got.

Here is the output I get from ndiswrapper.

```
root@orwell:/home/faheem# ndiswrapper
install/manage Windows drivers for ndiswrapper

usage: ndiswrapper OPTION
-i inffile       install driver described by 'inffile'
-a devid driver  use installed 'driver' for 'devid' (dangerous)
-r driver        remove 'driver'
-l               list installed drivers
-m               write configuration for modprobe
-ma              write module alias configuration for all devices
-mi              write module install configuration for all devices
-v               report version information

where 'devid' is either PCIID or USBID of the form XXXX:XXXX,
as reported by 'lspci -n' or 'lsusb' for the card
```

After `modprobe ndiswrapper` I get

```
root@orwell:/home/faheem# lsmod | grep ndiswrapper
ndiswrapper           220250  0
```